# module diagram .

Tags: abstract-algebra

First, sorry for this ugly diagram, my arrow button is broke.
\begin{matrix}
& & F & & \\
&& \ \downarrow{f} &&\\
M&\overset{g}\twoheadrightarrow & N &\to& 0
\end{matrix}
row is exact, $f,g$ are $R$-homomorphisms and $F$ free. That is $f:F\to N$ and $g:M\to N$, 
I am asked to prove that there exist $h: F\to M$ such that $gh=f$.

This is what I got so far.

$F$ free so $Im(f)$ is a free submodule of $N$. $g$ is surjective so $Im(g)$ must contain $Im(f)$, hence the preimage of $g(Im(f))$ is subset(submodule?) of $M$.

It feels like i am almost done(assuming any of this is correct) but i can't seem to finish the argument.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I think what problem i am trying to solve is pretty clear. I want to show that there exist an homomorphism h: F--M s.t gh=f. I need help with finishing my argument or suggestions on how to solve the problem.

Comment: See your question now - is the editing correct?

Comment: What are you using as your definition of "free"?

Comment: thank you, almost correct. f: F--N.    @ Brian. that F admits a basis

Comment: Also, should the sequence be $M\to N\to O$ or $M\to N\to 0$?

Comment: It should be the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an $R$-basis $(e_i)$ of $F$. For each $i$, because $g$ is surjective, there is an element $m_i \in M$ such that $g(m_i) = f(e_i)$. Define $h\colon F \to M$ by taking $h(e_i) = m_i$ and extend linearly to an $R$-module homomorphism. It's part of the definition (or one definition) of freedom that you can do so. Because the $R$-module homomorphism $f\colon F \to N$ is determined entirely by what it does to the $e_i$, and you now, by definition, have $(g \circ h)(e_i) = f(e_i)$ for each $i$, you have $g \circ h = f$.

Comment: Thank you, i am unsure about what the following means though, "extend linearly to an R-module homomorphism"

Comment: The elements of $F$ can all be written as finite linear combinations $\sum_i r_i e_i$, where the $e_i$ are a basis and the $r_i$ are elements of $R$, all but finitely many equal to zero. For our new map $h$ to be $R$-linear (that is, an $R$-module homomorphism), we must have $h\big(\sum_i r_i e_i\big) = \sum_i r_i h(e_i) = \sum_i r_i m_i$, and given that we've already set $h(e_i) = m_i$, demanding this linearity now determines the map completely. That's what's nice about (and in fact the definition of) free modules and bases.